# React Insta stories play next set of stories on end of first set

Tags: reactjs, react-insta-stories

I am using this package to display Instagram like stories: https://github.com/mohitk05/react-insta-stories.

I have a set of stories from different persons in this structure:

```
    let people = [ {
    "name": "Sumesh",
    "stories": [
      {
        "url": "url of image",
        "type": "image"
      },
      {
        "url": "url of video",
        "type": "video"
      }
    ]
  },
  {......}
];
```

What I need is when first set of stories are completed (above eg:2), I need to load the next set of stories. I am setting current stories to a state "`items`", the using the prop "`onAllStoriesEnd`"
loads the next set of items in "items state".  But this doesn't work as expected. Has anyone a work around for this.

`<Stories stories={items} onAllStoriesEnd={setAllStoryEnd} />`

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for same, I fixed this by adding a `key` prop to the `Stories` component.